# Transformar metros em Pixels

Tags: android, google-maps

Gostaria de transformar um valor métrico em pixels para adicionar em um Marker.

Em versões anteriores utilizava se de seguinte forma:

```
import com.google.android.maps.Projection;
Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
float raio = projection.metersToEquatorPixels(metros);
```

Mas nas novas versões ( `com.google.android.gms.maps.Projection` ) este método não está disponível!

Como transformo metro em Pixels?